# Using OWIN TestServer, and ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, owin

I have a console app that starts one of our web projects with the following.

```
using (var server = TestServer.Create<Startup>())
```

On start up the web project needs to check values in it's web.config appSettings. However these are all missing.  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` shows the console apps appSettings and not the web projects.  To be clear the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` call is from inside the web project.

How can I get web project to use the web.config when running from the TestServer?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. At first, I just copied the whole web.config app settings section to the app.config of the test project. Then I discover [OwinHost.exe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/owinhost), which (as the name implies) simply looks for startup classes in the current directory and run them. Becuase of that, it will actually use the correct web.config. This is the code I am using right now, feel free to use it instead of TestServer:

```
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = Path.Combine(solutionRootPath, @"packages\OwinHost.3.0.1\tools\\OwinHost.exe"),
            WorkingDirectory = packageFolder,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        };

        var process = Process.Start(psi);

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
        };

        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
        };


        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Where the solutionRootPath is the directory contains the solution, and the packageFolder is the folder contains the binaries of your web project (the output directory of your project).